# Using KQL in the updateRefinersJSON method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, refiner

After weeks of searching I have been unable to find any documentation as to how to pass KQL values through the updateRefinersJSON method. I know there is a Boolean flag for KQL but nothing specifies if set to true what the syntax should be. I am attempting to check to see if the values in a multi-valued managed property are less than a date specified in the refiner and also greater than a date specified by the refiner. the refiner has a start date picker and an end date picker.